# Does GNU octave have a routine to generate antidiagonal and exchange matrices?

Tags: octave

I need to generate some antidiagonal matrices (matrices whose lower left to upper right corner elements are non-zero. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-diagonal_matrix) and Exchange matrices (matrices whose lower left to upper left corner diagonal is 1, and everything else is zero https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix). Does Octave have any inbuilt routine to generate them (like eye(n), or diag(1,2,4))?

Of course, I can otherwise write a for loop to generate these, but I would like to use a pre-existing routine, if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no single function, but you can easily use `flipud` or `fliplr` to flip a diagonal matrix up/down or left/right to get what you want:

```
>> flipud(eye(4))

ans =

     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0
     1     0     0     0
```